# Replacing all Alt Text Double Quotes with &quot;

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a bunch of images that uses double quotes in the alt text. I'd like to replace the double quotes with `&quot;`.

For instance `<img src="table.jpg" alt="40.5" table">` should be `<img src="table.jpg" alt="40.5&quot; table">`.

I'd like to use jQuery and tried using .replace but that ends up replacing the whole value.

How can I replace all double quotes for only the alt attributes?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Bigger question; why is your backend generating invalid html?

Comment: Doing this in client side JS is too late in the page lifecycle. You need to stop your server side logic spitting out invalid HTML.

Comment: $("img").prop("alt", Replace('"',"&quot;"));

Comment: @EvikGhazarian that's not going to work.  The value of `alt` will not contain any double quotes.

Comment: @Taplar it's not a double quote it s  '  "  '

Comment: `"` is a double quote....?

Comment: OP clearly states he wants to change 40.5" to 40.5&quot; >>> I'm changing " to &quot;

Comment: And you're missing the point that `alt="40.5" table"` will result in the value of the alt property being `40.5` **only** because the first double quote after it terminates the attribute

Comment: Then " has to be replaced before reaching to alt. Assume the alts are being generated dynamically???

Comment: one option is to remove attribute - table" , if it is always issue with table" -https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/OYWLyo

Comment: @EvikGhazarian Either the logic to fix the html will have to be created, which depending on how dynamic the alt text can be could be messy, but ideally this should be fixed in the html generation, which wouldn't be a javascript fix.

Comment: @Taplar Maybe we can do the trick wrap the alt in single quote <img src="table.jpg" alt='40.5" table'>

Comment: @Taplar good question. This should be built into Shopify so I'm not sure why it isn't working. I'm looking into it now.

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex to find the attribute value and then replace the double quotes with & then replace it with your substitution string

regex to find  `(?<=\balt=)[^\s]*`